# AWS Lambda as cron schedular

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, aws-lambda

I am not sure whether this question is relevant on SF or not.

Basically in our project we have couple of functions which needs to be executed at specified time OR on regular interval.  We have developed APIs for those tasks.  We are having an option of installing cron jobs on standalone VM and fire these APIs.  But I want to have better approach.

It would be great if AWS (may be Lambda) provide such functionality (work like cron schedular).. Will appreciate for any pointer or any alternative.

Regards

Comment: You can associate cloudwatch events as an event source while creating lamda. Cloud watch events lets you define cron scheduler expression. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-scheduled-events.html

Comment: You need to tell more about your functions like resource requirement, running time etc.,

Answer (score 0):

You can define the [Cloudwatch Rules](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/Create-CloudWatch-Events-Scheduled-Rule.html) that generated events based on Cron/frequency that you provided. These scheduled events can be used to [trigger your lambda funtion](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html).

---

You can also add API Gateway and a proxy lambda in your bucket to automate these process and make these scheduling serverless as below:

1. Define your lambda function(let's call it ACTOR_LAMBDA) that takes some input function parameter and executes something like storing in DB/publishing report/sending emails(or whatever your use-case is).
2. Define a proxy lambda function(let's call it PROXY_LAMBDA) that creates a cloudwatch rule based on parameters like cron/frequency passed as input. The cloudwatch rules created by PROXY_LAMBDA lambda will trigger the ACTOR_LAMBDA.
3. Create a [POST API using AWS API gateway to invoke the PROXY_LAMBDA](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-lambda-non-proxy-integration.html). This API basically passes the input parameters(like cron/frequency/rule name/rule inputs/ lambda trigger etc) for PROXY_LAMBDA for creating the cloudwatch rules.

---

*`Result`*: You have an API that you can use to generate the Cron or frequency based trigger. And your ACTOR_LAMBDA will be auto-triggered based on the cron/frequency you defined.

For simplicity, you can also add a UI layer that calls API gateway. Or Alternatively, you can use [POSTMAN](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-use-postman-to-call-api.html) or any of the methods provided in [this AWS doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-call-api.html) to make a direct call to your API.